# Can "active processes" be larger than "max_children" for PHP-FPM

Tags: php, fpm

Having set the pool to static with max_children to 5 I would expect the metric "active processes" to be 5 or below. Sending 10 concurrent requests will have "active processes" report more than 5 (e.g. 10, 12, 25, ...).

Is this valid behaviour?

Pool configuration:

```
# grep -v ";" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf | grep -Ev "^$"
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
pm = static
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
pm.max_requests = 500
pm.status_path = /status
ping.response = pong
slowlog = log/$pool.log.slow
request_slowlog_timeout = 0
request_terminate_timeout = 0
```

**Expected result:**
Metric "active processes" from /status should be below 5.

**Actual result:**
Metric "active processes" from /status is above 5.

Comment: Some more detail about the web server, the client you are using to test with, and the ~method of determining “active processes”~ (I see /status endpoint, my mistake) would help.

Comment: I think Enrico is asking with `pm.max_children = 5` shouldn't "active processes" be <= 5 as well? I see the same thing with my PHP-FPM setup, php status shows anywhere between 7 and 10. And that is not even "total processes" (which is a sum of "active processes" and "idle processes")

Comment: What's the value of `max_children_reached` on `/status`? I suppose it's 0.

Comment: @MarkFox This is just a normal PHP-FPM set up. It's mainly to get correct reporting for https://github.com/hipages/php-fpm_exporter

Comment: How does full response from `/status` looks like?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? @EnricoStahn

Answer (score -1):

According to the PHP FPM documentation when `pm` is set to `static` the only setting that determines the number of child processes is `pm.max_children`. As you expect, that should determine the start and max number.

A couple things to consider:

1. After changing the configuration did you restart both PHP-FPM and NGINX ? Something like:

> sudo service php-fpm5 restart
>   sudo service nginx restart

2. Is it possible you are altering the wrong config file (perhaps one that is in the wrong path?). You might try changing some other value and confirm that it is affecting the web server as intended.
3. Is it possible that you have multiple pools configured and that the `/status` page is giving you a report for multiple pools.

Comment: While I think you have provided a good response, it's not a valid answer to my question. Imo I believe it's PHP-FPM that is faulty. I have created a bug report in the PHP bug tracker. See more details here: https://github.com/hipages/php-fpm_exporter#why---phpfpmfix-process-count